# hexa value to character string

Tags: php, sql-server, vb.net

I have hex value and want to convert in a character string. I tried much but it returns some symbols.

```
0xA663BEF9D2E71A66D949407D4FD009CFB2C35A348858C2FDF873E1C4EED89CA0373E0C1
4281EEED1EE8014966238E3F36F02320404670FDEBA3333B11AABFD828B255BF0F95C6F688FD29E6C49C1AA22
```

Answer (score 0):

In php, things like datatypes dont rly exist. Infact, there are only variant values, so php decides himself if he needs it as a string or as a number. If you want to print that ... number, you have to put it in quotes like that:

```
echo "0xA663BEF9D2E71A66D949407D4FD009CFB2C35A348858C2FDF873E1C4EED89CA0373E0C14281
EEED1EE8014966238E3F36F02320404670FDEBA3333B11AABFD828B255BF0F95C6F688FD29E6C49C1AA22";
```

If you got it in a variable, print the variable, nothing more

```
echo $var;
```

Edit: I just noticed you tagged it vb.net too. In that case, ignore my answer.